# How to get the full URL of the current page and change domain of it?

Tags: permalinks

For example, the current url is:

```
https://example1.com/hello-world
```

I want to display this url under the showing article and also change the domain to:

```
https://newdomain.com/hello-world
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you guys a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it’s a page or post, then you can get its url with [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/).

And to change the domain, you can do some simple string replacing with `str_replace`.

So here’s the code:

```
echo str_replace( 'OLD_DOMAIN', 'NEW DOMAIN', get_permalink() );
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple PHP `str_replace()` ought to do it. Although you don't mention *where* (or even why) you need this.

```
$oldstring = "https://www.example.com/here/there/"; 
$search_for = "example.com"; 
$replace_it = "newdomain.com"; 
$newstring = str_replace($search_for, $replae_it, $oldstring);
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php.

Comment: Thank you very much! I want to display the url under the current article.